# How to trigger revert with hardhat

Tags: contract-development, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I want to use hardhat to test my contract.Here is my Contract. When I deliberately make a mistake which will trigger `require(,"The service is not passed")` and run `npx hardhat test`,I expect to see the test is passed, but it failed. The error message is  `ProviderError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert The service is not passed` . I can't understand the bug had been triggered, but he wasn't caught by Hardhat.I'm sure there are no errors with my contract address and the test network. How should I fix this problem?

```
it("User2 Can't Response User1's Service Requirement", async function () {
         await expect(service.connect(user2Signer).respondService(1)).to.be.revertedWith("The service is not passed");
      });
```

```
 function respondService(uint256 serviceId) public {
        require(serviceRecords[serviceId].isPass,"The service is not passed");
        require(serviceRecords[serviceId].status == ServiceStatus.Pending, "Service status is not pending");
        require(msg.sender != serviceRecords[serviceId].provider, "Provider cannot respond to own service");
        serviceRecords[serviceId].receiver = msg.sender;
        serviceRecords[serviceId].status = ServiceStatus.Responded;
    }
```